# Trying to use BindingUtils in Flash AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am not able to make this code work in AS3.0 ( Flash ) with Flex SDK 4.0 included.

```
 import mx.binding.utils.*;


 [Bindable]
 var myValue:int = 0;
 var cw:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(myValueChanged, this, "myValue");
 addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME , ef);

 function ef(e:Event):void
 {
    trace("hello",getTimer());
    myValue = getTimer();
 }

 function myValueChanged(o:Object):void
 {
    trace("myValue: " + myValue.toString());
 }
```

The output i get is :

```
myValue: 0
hello 157
hello 168
hello 171
hello 177
....
....
```

and so on.

But I expect the correct output should be :

```
myValue: 0
hello 157
myValue: 157
hello 168
myValue: 168
hello 171
myValue: 171
hello 177
myValue: 177
....
....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how the Flash Pro compiler treats this stuff (I always use the free mxmlc compiler from the Flex SDK).

Does this work for you?

```
package
{
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.utils.getTimer;
  import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;

  public class BindingExample extends Sprite {

    private var model:Model;

    public function BindingExample()
    {
      model = new Model();
      BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, 'spy', model, ['value']);
      addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnterFrame);
    }

    public function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
      model.value = getTimer();
    }

    public function set spy(value:int):void
    {
      trace('Bound property set to: ' + value);
    }
  }
}

class Model
{
  [Bindable]
  public var value:int;
}
```

If not, try this for the Model definition:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

class Model extends EventDispatcher
{
  private var _value:int;

  [Bindable("valueChange")]
  public function get value():int
  {
    return _value;
  }

  public function set value(value:int):void
  {
    if (_value != value)
    {
      trace('Model property set to: ' + value);
      _value = value;
      dispatchEvent(new Event("valueChange"));
    }
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try this for the Model:

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import mx.events.PropertyChangeEvent;
import mx.events.PropertyChangeEventKind;

class Model extends EventDispatcher
{
  private var _value:int;

  [Bindable("propertyChange")]
  public function get value():int
  {
    return _value;
  }

  public function set value(value:int):void
  {
    if (_value != value)
    {
      trace('Model property set to: ' + value);
      var oldValue:int = _value;
      _value = value;
      dispatchEvent(new PropertyChangeEvent(
        PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, false, false,
        PropertyChangeEventKind.UPDATE, "value", oldValue, value, this));
    }
  }
}
```

Or, perhaps with an ObjectProxy:

```
package
{
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.utils.getTimer;
  import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
  import mx.utils.ObjectProxy;

  public class BindingExample extends Sprite {

    private var model:ObjectProxy;

    public function BindingExample()
    {
      model = new ObjectProxy({value: 0});
      BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, 'spy', model, ['value']);
      addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnterFrame);
    }

    public function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
      model.value = getTimer();
    }

    public function set spy(value:int):void
    {
      trace('Bound property set to: ' + value);
    }
  }
}
```

All of the above work fine when compiling with mxmlc. I'd avoid the ObjectProxy as it's the least typesafe.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Except 1st code block, the combination of 2nd, 3rd and 4th code block work like breeze! :)

Answer (score 3):

Data binding only works with Flex.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" enterFrame="ef(event)">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.binding.utils.*;

            [Bindable]
            public var myValue:int = 0;
            private var cw:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(myValueChanged, this, "myValue");

            private function ef(e:Event):void
            {
                trace("hello", getTimer());
                myValue = getTimer();
            }

            private function myValueChanged(o:Object):void
            {
                trace("myValue: " + myValue.toString());
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: I don't see logic behind, why it can't work in Flash, if i am using the same Flex SDK ( that makes it possible in Flex )

Comment: Binding is just actionscript - but it is added by the flex compiler (which is not the same as the compiler in flash pro). Youll need to compile using mxmlc (see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcc.html) to take advantage of [Bindable]

Comment: Skabir is right.  When you use the [Bindable] metadata, the mxml compiler generates a getter/setter for the property that is bindablwe. The setter method dispatches an event when the property changes. You could make this work with BindingUtils if you did the same yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that @Lee Burrows is right. Binding will work, if you dispatch the event yourself. The Flex compiler (mxmlc) will translate the [Bindable] metadata into Actionscript code, and the Flash Pro compiler ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I am not able to make this code work in AS3.0 ( Flash ) with Flex SDK 4.0 included.

I take it this means you are already using the mxmlc compiler, which is necessary for the Bindable metatag to work.

As I understand it, adding the Bindable meta tag to a variable is a way to listen for dispatches of a `PropertyChangeEvent`:

The [Flex 4.6 API docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc5.html) state:

> [When using Bindable on a variable] The Flex compiler automatically generates an event named propertyChange, of type PropertyChangeEvent, for the property.

Basically a simpler way to do `myValue.addEventListener(...)`

So the variable we want to be Bindable must be of a type that extends `EventDispatcher` or implements `IEventDispatcher`. This is not the case with the primitive `int` which is the type of the variable you are trying to make bindable. `Bindable` on an `int` will not work.

To make it work you could wrap the `int` variable in a custom class `BindableInteger` that implements `IEventDispatcher`. Another options is to use [ObjectProxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html), which allows you to add EventListeners and make an object bindable even though it doesn't extend `EventDispatcher` or implements `IEventDispatcher`.

Also, note that you need to make your variable public, protected or private for Bindable to work.

Flex 4.6 docs on [Using the Bindable meta tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc5.html):

> You can use the [Bindable] metadata tag (...) [b]efore a public, protected, or private property defined as a variable to make that specific property support binding.

This will not work:

```
[Bindable] var myValue:int = 0;
```

but this will:

```
[Bindable] public var myValue:int = o;
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried that too ( used the code of user "fsbmain" who replied in this thread ). But still didnot work.

Comment: hmm...
Actually a member also suggested me this : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html
Which is somewhat similar to your updated answer but inbuilt.

Comment: I've updated my answer to mention ObjectProxy. Both wrapping your own type and using ObjectProxy will work.

Comment: Thanks for update Gunnar. You said => "I take it this means you are already using the mxmlc compiler, which is necessary for the Bindable metatag to work.".  No, i am making use of sdk only for the mx package. Ultimately it's Flash pro compiler which is used. But anyways, it was a learning experience, to go through your inputs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Binding works for class properties, and doesn't work with local variables so you need to create the class:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher;

public class astest extends Sprite
{

    [Bindable]
    public var myValue:int = 0;

    public function astest()
    {
        var cw:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(myValueChanged, this, "myValue");
        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME , ef);
    }

    protected function ef(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("hello",getTimer());
        myValue = getTimer();
    }

    protected function myValueChanged(o:Object):void
    {
        trace("myValue: " + myValue.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I had done that also. But it doesnot work. Here is a link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036377/bindings-failing-when-compiled-through-flash-ide , that suggests for checking "swc" ON. Which is a known bug for activating as3 metagtags. 
I did that too but still it doesnot work